# php using $_GET

Tags: php, get

i have link php program - its activation link as
"activation.php?user=jack?hash=abcd?id=20

When i use 
$_GET['user'] its gives the complete url not just name ? how to get results so that i have

```
> $_GET['user']  as jack 
> $_GET['hash']  as abcd 
> $_GET['id']  as 20
```

Comment: thanks guys...its quite  embarrassing i missed something very basic :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `GET` parameters are malformed - your code should work as expected when your `GET` parameters are properly delimited by the ampersand (`&`) character, like this:

```
activation.php?user=jack&hash=abcd&id=20
```